# What is more efficient of Querying the database

Tags: java, mysql, performance, java-8, coding-efficiency

Should we query the table with more filtering by adding multiple conditions/ where clauses to SQL query and get the specific data 
Or pull all the data and do filtering in our java class.

Looking for efficient way of coding practices

Example :

A table with multiple columns Id, Name, Place.

I need to pull the list of ids with Place should be form placesList and Name should match namesList.

1)

```
(SELECT id 
   FROM Person p 
  WHERE p.name IN (<name_list>) 
    AND p.place IN (<place_list>) 
  order 
     by p.id asc)

public List<Long> getIds(@BindIn("name_list") List<String> name_list, @BindIn("place_list") List<String> place_list);
```

or

2)

```
(SELECT id 
   FROM Person p)
```

public List getIds();
apply java8 filters to the result

Note: Above example i took name place for easy understanding. In Real time, data is huge and have multiple fields and rows in the table. The list used to filter is also large.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is query with required filters on database  and which will reduce amount of data fetch you from applicaion and db back and forth  and also it will reduce time on I/O operations(since it involves some latency to transfer large amount of data over network).
 also reduces overhead of memory need to process large amount of data on application side.

Also  when you are running query and filtering on multiple fields you can add  indexes(if necessary) on fields it will improve query fetch time.

Hope it answers

Answer (score 0):

You always want to perform things in the database if possible. You want to avoid transferring data from the database to your application, using up memory, just to remove it there.

Databases are very efficient at doing those things, so you'll want to use them to their full extent.

Answer (score 0):

Query the database directly instead of downloading data in Java application. It will reduce the latency from the database to your java application.

But be very careful when using user inputs in the filter. Make sure that you have sanitized the user input before using them in a query to the database to avoid SQL injection.

If you are worried about security more than performance then filter the data in Java App (if the data is not massive in size).

But I strongly recommend filtering the data on the database itself by ensuring necessary safeguards.